# Using symmetry to solve for electric flux

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry

I can't seem to figure out why wouldn't the flux be 0 through a disk in this instance:

[image]

These are two **identical** point charges. Wouldn't the scalar product with one be $cos\theta$ and the other $cos(180-\theta)$ so they cancel each other at each point? I think there's a simple concept I'm missing here and generally in calculating flux.

Comment: charges sign is also the same, or is it $q_+$ and $q_-$ ?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Are you asking along n or along the orthogonal to n?

Comment: Along the disk generally. What do you mean? Will the total flux be 0?

Comment: Why do you think the flux should not be zero?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the setup flipped vertically. The charges swap positions and the surface stays in the same place because it is midway between the charges. The electric field everywhere is flipped vertically as well. However, because the charges are identical, swapping changes nothing, so the electric field everywhere must have stayed the same. Since the surface did not move during the flip, the electric field cannot not have changed after flipping. This can only be the case if the electric field in the surface has no component parallel to the normal vector, since that component would have been flipped. So, the electric field is perpendicular to the surface normal (parallel to the surface), and the flux is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at net electric vector field in your case :

[image]

Gauss law states that electric flux through a closed surface is :
$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf {E} ={\frac {\rho }{\varepsilon _{0}}} $$

This resolves along $x$ direction to :

$$ \frac {\partial \mathbf {E}_x}{\partial x} = {\frac {\rho }{\varepsilon _{0}}} $$

Of course we have no closed surface here, which is required for a full application of Gauss law, but partial application of it says that for an electric flux we must have electric field gradient. Your net $\mathbf {E}_x$ is zero, so electric flux along $x$ is zero too.

Comment: Shouldn't it be sufficient to notice the canceling in the direction parallel to the normal and negate the x direction because it causes no flux due to it being perpendicular to the normal of the disk?

Comment: Probably, yes. But the point is that it's very easy to achieve electric field gradient along $x$. Just protrude slightly your surface along $x$ direction, giving a thin cylinder of height $dx$. Now you will have a closed cylinder surface, albeit very small. And it can be shown that in that case there would be **some** electric flux along $x$ in it. So for the sake of reason, I would include Gauss law conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

to electric field lines never intersect so , imagine electric field lines from the charges they are in same direction, due to similar nature of charges , **so they would never intersect at surface so there cannot be any flux through it at all, also electric field along direction area vector would be 0 electric field would only exist at 90 degrees to area vector  (if there is field).**
electric field concept was purely on **basis of symmetry**, as in the plane of surface its a mirror image so electric field would be equal but in opposite direction(due to similar charge)

Comment: also see explanation of @Mark H, he also explained this concept of symmetry pretty well